# Changing the chapter title font back to \rmfamily

Tags: fonts

I am using the Kerkis font to write a chapter. However, I wish the change the font of the chapter title back to the default font. I have tried all the possible codes. But none of them are working. Here is the preamble I am using.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{blindtext}



\usepackage{kerkis}

% To change the chapter appearence style
\usepackage{titlesec, sectsty}

\titleformat{\chapter}[hang]
{\normalfont\huge\bfseries\rmfamily}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{20pt}{\Huge}



\begin{document}


\blinddocument



\end{document}
```

The result I am getting is the following
[image]

The font family is not changed. Also, I wish to keep the chapter title in a grey color box.
Does anyone know the way it is done?

Comment: Please always ask one question per question. BTW: Your chapters *are* in `\rmfamily`. `kerkis` changes `\rmdefault`, `\sfdefault` and `\ttdefault`. So all standard families are replaced. If you want the chapter headings in a font not provides by `kerkis` you could, e.g., use `\fontfamily{cmr}\selectfont`. See a LaTeX introduction or the `fntguide` for information about `\fontfamily`, `\usefont`, `\selectfont` etc.